# Adjusting a queue

Tags: php, object-oriented

I have a function that takes all items in a queue and increments their order (used to allow insertion earlier in the queue).

```
private function incrementAllQueueItemsWithOrderLargerThan($order_larger_than) {
    return $this->queue()
           ->where('order', '>=', $order_larger_than)
           ->increment('order');
}
```

This feels really unwieldy. Can anyone suggest a better name for both the function and its parameter?

Comment: `shiftOrderFrom` ?

Comment: `private function shiftQueueAfterOrder($from)` or `private function shiftAfter(Queue $queue, $field, $value)` to be called as `$this->shiftAfter($this->queue(), 'order', $from);` which makes it more generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the word "queue" from the method name:

1. If the main responsibility of the containing class is working with a queue,
   then the word "queue" should be in the name of the class itself,
   and redundant in the method name.
2. If the main responsibility of the containing class is *not* working with a queue,
   then you might want to reorganize the code, extracting the queue manipulations to a dedicated class, in which case the previous point applies.
3. If the main responsibility of the containing class is *not* working with a queue,
   but the queue is actually just a minor element in it,
   then it might be better to hide the fact that the class is working with a queue (as opposed to an array or linked list).
   You could think of the class as working with a *collection of items*,
   the method name doesn't have to leak the internal detail that it's actually a queue.

You can also drop "all" from the name: let it be just implied.

As for the parameter name `$order_larger_than` I think simply `limit` would be more natural.

Unfortunately, the `OrderLargerThan` is a bit misleading:
I would guess it means `> limit`, but the code uses `>= limit`.
So it would be better to correct that,
which will unfortunately make it longer: `OrderLargerThanOrEqual`.
You might consider shortening "LargerThanOrEqual" as "LTE".
I know at least 2 languages/frameworks that do that (Bash, Django).

Applying all the above, how about this:

```
private function incrementItemsWithOrderLTE($limit) {
    return $this->queue()
           ->where('order', '>=', $limit)
           ->increment('order');
}
```